# android: facebook query FQL tries to retrieve the photo src from photo_src table

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql, photo

Recently , I realized my application can't retrieve any image src from facebook using the table photo_src

e.g. query Select pid From photo_src where size = '960X960'.

It works fine previously and able to get the source of the photo on facebook but somehow now i can't retrieve the image at all.

From the description on their website, the size property: A string representing the max size of the image returned. For example, 640X640. Note: If you want an exact dimension, use width and height

It should return a photo that maximum in the list wasn't....

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Same here for my application. It looks like Facebook has made a change or introduced a bug that it no longer treats it as a parameter for max size. I used to use size='480x480'. However, it only returns with an exact match.

We should report a bug to Facebook. For me, I would likely simply remove the size parameter and select the best matched photos in my own application.